# MongoDB :: are Mongo IDs unique across collections?

Tags: mongodb

Can Mongo IDs have the same value in different collections in the same database?

Comment: It might help http://www.code-sample.com/2016/07/are-mongodb-ids-unique.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possibility of duplicate Mongo ObjectId's being generated in two different collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The uniqueness constraint for _id is per collection, so yes - one and the same ID can occur once per Collection.

It's however very unlikely, if not impossible, for the same ID to be generated twice. So in order for this to happen you would have to manually insert duplicate IDs.

Comment: how unlikely is it? Should I code with the assumption that this will never happen to me unless I insert duplicates manually?

Comment: Yes, it is very unlikely since it is a guid. You should not accidentally be able to hit a collision very easily.

Comment: Check out the MongoDB docs on the ObjectID to learn more about why its seemingly impossible: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

Comment: It is almost impossible but the problem lies in the drivers generating their own ObjectIds. So basically you can have two clients generating the same id but its quite unlikely and depends on the driver implementation.

Comment: Here's good document about the uniqueness of ObjectIDs and other alternatives in case the default one doesn't suit you : https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb

Comment: I've actually just had a case where I had multiple collisions due to batch inserting in multiple collections, large amount of data, since MongoId is mostly based upon unix timestamp and some random characters.