# trello API are id values unique across all objects

Tags: trello

as the subject says - are the id values of all objects unique? For example is it possible (not probable) for a card to share the same id of a list/board etc ?

My guess would be 'yes' but just wanted to check.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` values are meant to be unique across all accounts and all objects.

The ids are in fact the document `_id`s associated with the records in the [mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/) database.  They are required to be unique per collection (i.e. no two lists or members should ever have the same `_id`).  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237) about the probability of an `_id` collision.  (In short, there shouldn't be any collisions)

In fact, the Trello web client and API depend on the `id`s being unique, so it should be safe for you to make the same assumption.