# How to insert a doc into mongodb using mongoose and get the generated id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to operate mongodb. Now, for testing, I want to inserting some data into mongodb by native connection.

But the question is how to get the generated id after inserting?

I tried:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongo://localhost/shuzu_test');

var conn = mongoose.connection;

var user = {
    a: 'abc'
};

conn.collection('aaa').insert(user);

console.log('User:');
console.log(user);
```

But it prints:

```
{ a: 'abc' }
```

There is no `_id` field.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can generate `_id` yourself and send it to the database.

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var user = {
  a: 'abc',
  _id: new ObjectID()
};

conn.collection('aaa').insert(user);
```

This is one of my favourite features of MongoDB. If you need to create a number of objects, that are linked to each other, you don't need to make numerous round-trips between app and db. You can generate all ids in the app and then just insert everything.

Comment: Doesn't   new ObjectID()   need to do a round trip to get an "available" ID?...  otherwise, would there not be an extremely small chance of a collision?  (( for instance, on MSSQL, NEWID() is compliant with RFC4122...  and ensures no collisions, but it occurs on the DB side.))

Comment: I did some further research, and came across this SOQuestion [https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694803/1327508] which explains both how the oid is generated & the 3 (+1 in comment) scenarios for collision...  & my answer is essentially, "no, you're correct", because of how the oid is generated.

Comment: seems that IObjectID  is depracted , "invalid schema configuration: `_id` schematype definition is invalid"

Answer (score 16):

If you use .save then you'll get the _id back in the callback function.

```
const User = require('../models/user.js');    

var user = new User({
  a: 'abc'
});

user.save(function (err, results) {
  console.log(results._id);
});
```

Comment: Getting User is not undefined

Comment: I was using `User` as an example model. You'll need to include the model from whichever file it is exporting from.

Comment: Updated with example user model

Answer (score 6):

If you like using Promises:

```
const collection = conn.collection('aaa');
const instance = new collection({ a: 'abc' });
instance.save()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.id);  // this will be the new created ObjectId
    })
    .catch(...)
```

Or if you're using Node.js >= 7.6.0:

```
const collection = conn.collection('aaa');
const instance = new collection({ a: 'abc' });
try {
    const result = await instance.save();
    console.log(result.id);  // this will be the new created ObjectId
} catch(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Update method with upsert: true option

```
aaa.update({
    a : 'abc'
}, {
    a : 'abc'
}, {
    upsert: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const User = require('./userModel.js');

const InsertUser = async (req, res) => {
    // Obtain the user object from req.body (assuming you have bodyParser or similar middleware configured)
    const userObject = req.body;

    try {
        await User.create(userObject);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'User inserted successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to insert user' });
    }
};
```