# Mongoose: Get doc _id after upsert

Tags: node.js, mongoose

is there any way to get the record _id after an upsert?

I've seen this post ([How to insert a doc into mongodb using mongoose and get the generated id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520501/how-to-insert-a-doc-into-mongodb-using-mongoose-and-get-the-generated-id)), but this is oriented only to inserts, not updates.

Also, using the MongoDB you can use get the _id using getlasterror (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/ehZ11QY-OUw), but Mongoose doesn't provides access to it (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoose-orm/pSv6WrasvWg)

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use Mongoose's [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOneAndUpdate) method with `upsert: true` in the options object.

```
var query = { name: 'borne' },
    data = { name: 'jason borne' },
    options = { upsert: true };
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, options, function (err, object) {
    /* use object._id */
});
```

Comment: Note that if you want the *updated* document returned, and in cases where it didn't exist and was upserted the *new* document, you will want to add new: true to the options:

options = { upsert: true, new: true };

Answer (score 1):

If you want the updated document returned, and in cases where it didn't exist and was upserted the new document. Below is the option you need to set.

set new: true to the options: `options = { upsert: true, new: true };`

Source: Based on Jamiel's comment, I am adding his comment as an answer as it was hard time finding for me to get that _id when no document existed and created by upsert (And I was trying to create my own extended method).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with promises:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, options, function (err, object) {
})).then((result) => {
    /* return result.upserted[0]._id */
})
```

...where `result` is the following:

```
{ n: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  upserted: [ { index: 0, _id: /* some id */ } ],
  ok: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateUser = await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: uid },
    {
        name: name
        time: createdAt,
    }
).session(session);

let shallowCopy = {...updateUser}._doc;
console.log("shallowCopy", shallowCopy);
```

> sometime we ned to delete some parameter like id.
> > **._doc** will get updated/inserted data
> you may delete id using js delete operator

```
delete shallowCopy.id;
```