# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Upsert _id null?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to have a single method that either creates or updates a document for a policy.  Searching and trying different techniques like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215689/mongoose-get-doc-id-after-upsert), I have come up with a null _id for my document.  Using findByIdAndUpdate has a similar affect.

I see a document inserted in the collection, but the _id field is null:

```
exports.savePolicy = function (plcy, callback) {
    console.log('priority is : ' + plcy.priority)
    try {
        var policy = new Policy(plcy);
        var query = {_id: plcy._id};  //this may be null
        var update = {
            name: plcy.name || defaults.policyDefaults.name,
            longDescription: plcy.longDescription || defaults.policyDefaults.longDescription,
            shortDescription: plcy.shortDescription || defaults.policyDefaults.shortDescription,
            priority: plcy.priority, colorHex: plcy.colorHex || defaults.policyDefaults.colorHex,
            settings: plcy.settings || [],
            parentPolicyId: plcy.parentPolicyId || null
        }

        Policy.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, {upsert: true}, function (err, data) {
            callback(err, data);
        });

    } catch (e) {
        log.error('Exception while trying to save policy: ' + e.message);
        callback(e, null);
    }
```

Is there something that can be done to get the _id not to be null when its not an update?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I was getting this same problem.  I ended up checking for the _id manually and then calling either findOneAndUpdate for an update or create() for a new record.

Answer (score 25):

`null` is a valid `_id` value in MongoDB, so if you don't want it used in new docs you must ensure that a `null` value is replaced with a new `ObjectID` in `query`:

```js
var query = {_id: plcy._id};
if (!query._id) {
    query._id = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID();
}

// the rest stays the same...
```

Comment: We use ObjectIds to infer creation timestamp. Wouldn't it be best that ObjectIds are created on server side instead of clients creating them?

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem and couldn't figure out a way to get it to work. I ended up writing my own upsert method like so....

```
var upsert = function(model, data, f){
  if (!data._id) {
    model.create(data, f);
  } else {
    var id = data._id;
    delete data._id;
    model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, data, f);
  }
}
```

That allows me to call it for any of my models with one line of code...

```
upsert(Team, team, f);
```

There might be a better way to do it, but this is working for me.  I can do updates and inserts and I don't get a null _id on insert.

Comment: Well, you can solve this problem using something like that:
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id || Mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }, {$set: attrs}, { upsert: true, new: true })

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to update document if there's an ID or create a new document if there's no ID is:

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id ?? new mongoose.Types.ObjectId() }, updates, { upsert: true });
```

Note the use of the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) which allows 0 as a valid id. The `updates` object doesn't need to contain an `id` property, as mongoose will [add it automatically](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html):

> if no document matches filter, MongoDB will insert one by combining filter and update as shown below.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to JohnnyHK for a helpful answer above. I came up with a one-liner since it's used so frequently:

```
query = args._id ? { _id: args._id } : { _id: new ObjectId() };
```

It relies on the following require:

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Comment: Improvement would be
query = {_id: args._id !=null ? args._id : new ObjectId() }

Answer (score 1):

I am not using Mongoose, but I run into similar issue with MongoDB. For Upsert action when new object was inserted the MongoDB was setting `null` to `_id`.

I was calling:

```
findOneAndUpdate({my_id:'my_unique_id'}, obj, {upsert: true})
```

where `obj._id` was `undefined`.

The problem was that `_id` was present on list of keys `Object.keys(obj)`. I found that I was assigning `obj._id = some_variable`, where `some_variable` was `undefined`, and that was causing `_id` to appear on a list of keys.

I applied workaround by calling right before upsert:

```
if (_.isUndefined(obj._id)) {
  delete obj._id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful (from [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists-upsert)):

> If you specify an _id field in either the query parameter or replacement document, MongoDB uses that _id field in the inserted document.

So when you write:

```js
model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, data, f);
```

And `id` is `null`, it will insert a document with `null` as id.

Answer (score 0):

Since we can now add default properties while destructuring objects in JavaScript, in the case that we are checking to see if a document exists, I find this the easiest way to either query via an existing _id or create a new one in the same operation, avoiding the null id problem:

// someController.js using a POST route

```
async function someController(req, res) {
  try {
  const {
    // the default property will only be used if the _id doesn't exist
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    otherProp,
    anotherProp
  } = req.body;
  const createdOrUpdatedDoc = await SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id
    },
    {
      otherProp,
      anotherProp
    },
    {
      new: true,
      upsert: true
    }
  ).exec();
  return res.json(201).json(createdOrUpdatedDoc);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.json(400).send({
      error,
      message: "Could not do this"
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try setting 'new' parameter to true:

```
{ upsert: true, new: true }
```

More info: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2939

Answer (score -3):

Try setting the upsert parameter to true in your call to update. From the mongoid docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter

> Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.