# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate upsert doesn't create a new _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use findOneAndUpdate to update or create a new document. The problem is if it creates a new document it doesn't generate any id for it (or Mongo doesn't) what of course, is not appropriate. What am I doing wrong?

```
SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id, user: req.body.user}, req.body, {new: true, upsert: true}, function(err, updatedObject){
            if (err || !updatedObject){
                return res.json({result: false});
            }
            return res.json({result: true, id: updatedObject._id});//<--null
        });
```

It creates a new document but its _id is set up null.

NB It's not about single method like here ([Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Upsert _id null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244363/mongoose-findoneandupdate-upsert-id-null)) I just want it NOT TO BE null when a new document is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Upsert \_id null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244363/mongoose-findoneandupdate-upsert-id-null)

Comment: You must be passing `null` in `req.body.id`. That's why it's getting saved as `null` as it doesn't find the record with the matching `_id`.

Comment: @TarushArora if it's a new object there is no way to get _id *before* it's saved into database. Of course, I can generate it but I assumed that it's Mongodb's responsibility. If MongoDB can't generate it on its own, I start thinking there is something very wrong with Mongodb.