# _id not populated by findOneAndUpdate for Mongoose/ Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code that I'm using to either update a product if I have a matching pId or create that product with a new _id if a match is not found. I am getting a **MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'** which I know is because I am using `new Product` on my product object which is creating the _id field. The problem is if I remove that I get Mongo entries that do not have an _id field. I am looking to create a product entry with an automatically generated _id field if that product is not in the DB already however I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var item = req.body;
    var pId = item.pId; 
    var sId  = 1;
   
   const product = new Product({
     sId: sId,
     section: item.section,
     details:{name: item.name,
              price:  item.price,
              image: item.image,
              description: item.description
            }
    });

    Product.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': pId, 'sId': sId}, 
    product, { upsert: true, new:true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, 
    function(err, result) {
      
      res.sendStatus(200);
   
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Product Model

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
sId: {type: Number, required: true},
section: {type: Number, default:0},
details:{
    name:  {type: String, required:true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    image: String,
    description: {type: String, required:true}
  }
},
{
timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } 
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I need to specific the _id of the new entry in the query of the findOneAndUpdate

[Mongoose findOneAndUpdate Upsert _id null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244363/mongoose-findoneandupdate-upsert-id-null)

```
 var query =  {'_id': pId, 'sId': sId};
  if (!query._id){// add _id to query
      query._id = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID();
 }

 Product.findOneAndUpdate(query, 
    product, { upsert: true, new:true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true }, 
    function(err, result) {
      console.log('Product Submitted: '+result);
    res.send(result);
    
  })
```