# Mongoose (Typegoose) extension method type error

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

Currently when id is provided to findOneAndUpdate, it doesn't return auto generated id.

So I have created extension method to overcome this issue. But typescript is complaining about typings. Need help with that.

I have created extension method as below.

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface Model<T>
    extends NodeJS.EventEmitter,
      AcceptsDiscriminator {
    findOneAndUpsert<T>(
      filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
      update?: UpdateQuery<T>,
      options?: QueryOptions | null,
      callback?: (err: any, doc: T | null, res: any) => void,
    ): Promise<QueryWithHelpers<T | null, T>>; // Here I am getting error as "Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any, {}>'"
  }
}



mongoose.model.prototype.findOneAndUpsert = async function <
  T extends mongoose.Document<any, {}>
>(
  filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
  update?: UpdateQuery<T>,
  options?: QueryOptions | null,
  callback?: (err: any, doc: T | null, res: any) => void,
): Promise<QueryWithHelpers<T | null, T>> {
  const model = this as mongoose.Model<T>;
  if (filter.id) {
    return model.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
  } else {
    return model.findById((await model.create((update as any).$set)).id);
  }
};
```

I want to use it like below.

```
datasource = await DatasourceModel(
      await this.projectContext,
    ).findOneAndUpsert(
      { id: datasource.id },
      {
        $set: {
          name: datasource.name,
          type: datasource.type,
          source: datasource.source,
        },
      },
    );
```

My datasource model looks like below.

```
export class Datasource extends ModelBase {
  @prop()
  authTokenId?: number;
}

export const DatasourceModel = (connection: Connection) => {
  return getModelForClass(Datasource, connection);
};
```

during declaration I am getting error as "Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document<any, {}>'"?

If I write `"T extends mongoose.Document<any, {}>"` in model declaration, then not giving error, but then during calling the method it gives error as `"Property 'name' is missing in type 'Document<any, {}>' but required in type 'Datasource'"`

Can anyone help with that what I need to do here?

Comment: what are the versions you are using (typescript, mongoose, typegoose), and did you already try to add option `new: true` to [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)

Comment: tpyegoose 5.9.1, typescript 4.2.4, mongoose 5.12.7

Comment: Tried new:true. But it is also not returning newly generated Id. It returns null Id.

Comment: Seems following is related...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244363/mongoose-findoneandupdate-upsert-id-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok following signature worked for me. I was adding extends to both signature and actual implementation. But in model signature extend is not required as by default it goes to extended only.

```
declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface Model<T>
    extends NodeJS.EventEmitter,
      AcceptsDiscriminator {
    findOneAndUpsert<T>( 
      filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
      update?: UpdateQuery<T>,
      options?: QueryOptions | null,
      callback?: (err: any, doc: T | null, res: any) => void,
    ): Promise<T>;
  }
}
```