# Node.js / Mongodb insert callback returning undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when I run the simple code below to insert a new document:

```
collectionUsers.insert({'name':'john'},function(err,records){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Id of new document added =  " + records[0]._id);
});
```

I get the following errors:

```
catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                             ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

Doesn't the callback function return an array?  I'm just trying to get the id of the new document and save it in a variable for future use.  Thanks for your help.

Alternatively, if I use insertOne instead, I get this output: 
Id of new document added = {"ok":1,"n":1}

But I want to use insert...

Comment: As [the documentation states](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpCallback), the callback gets called with a [`insertWriteOpResultObject`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpResult) object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `ops` object in `records` which contains inserted doc/docs.

Try:

```
collectionUsers.insert({'name':'john'},function(err,records){
   // You can explore more here
   console.log("record contents",JSON.stringify(records,null,4));
   // Desired output
   console.log("Id of new document added =  " + records.ops[0]._id);
});
```

Comment: When I add you line I get this output:  record contents [object Object]...why doesn't records just give me the document?  I have seen many examples with the same code and they don't return any errors.

Comment: Answer edited.
Its `npm mongodb` library implementation which give you this results. alternatively you can use `npm mongoose` which is wrapper over mongodb npm.
It will give you desired results, more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520501/how-to-insert-a-doc-into-mongodb-using-mongoose-and-get-the-generated-id)

Comment: With your stringify code I get this (same as if I were to use insertOne): {
    "ok": 1,
    "n": 1
}

Comment: @user2285490 `mongoose` is much more than just a wrapper. It's a great library, but perhaps a bit overkill just to get the desired result :-) The inserted document _is_ available through `records.ops`, as you suggest.

Comment: sorry guys...so why cant records access the name field?

Comment: which `mongodb` version you are using?
the latest version `2.1.2` gives all results

`record contents {
    "result": {
        "ok": 1,
        "n": 1
    },
    "ops": [
        {
            "name": "john",
            "_id": "56863232030094bc0da3017b"
        }
    ],
    "insertedCount": 1,
    "insertedIds": [
        "56863232030094bc0da3017b"
    ]
}
Id of new document added =  56863232030094bc0da3017b`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot user2285490 and robertklep.  I finally realized what the ops object in record is.  This is the api documentation for future reference:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpCallback