# MongoDB: Object ID Uniqueness

Tags: mongodb

Quick question: Does the Object ID in MongoDB unique throughout the entire Database? I am doing a one to many implementations with one common collection relating to different collections.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, here is a already existing good answer on stackoverflow :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle