# Is an _id created programatically unique?

Tags: php, mongodb

let's assume I do this:

```
$person = array(
   "_id" => new MongoId(),
   "name" => "Fabs",
   "city" => "Rome"
);

$people->save($person);
```

Can I be sure of the fact `_id` will be unique when `$person` is actually persisted? Because, after all, the id has been created "outside" of the DB (without the DB knowing) and there might well be that very id in the `people` collection already, no? I also understand it might be very unlikely but is it possible at all?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694803/46375

This should hold true for any mongo driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's *possible*, as it is with any other ID generation scheme that doesn't involve a central registry of IDs.  The chance of it happening is so low, though, that i can safely assert that you'll never see it happen unless malice is involved.

Comment: I thought so too. Only wanted to nake sure. Thanks