# Manually change MongoID

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Through the PHP problem when inserting stuff into MongoDB explained in the answer by Denver Matt in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle) I created duplicate IDs in a dataset in MongoDB. Fixing the PHP code is easy, but to be able to still use my dataset I wonder:

Can I change the MongoId manually without breaking something? Or can I just reset this ID somehow into a new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_id` field of a document is immutable, as discussed in [this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-limitations). Attempting to modify its value would result in an error/exception, as in:

```
> db.foo.drop()
> db.foo.insert({ _id: 1 })
> db.foo.update({ _id: 1 }, { $set: { _id: 3 }})
Mod on _id not allowed
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : 1 }
```

If you do need to alter the identifier of a document, you could fetch it, modify the `_id` value, and then re-persist the document using `insert()` or `save()`. `insert()` may be safer on the off chance that you new `_id` value conflicts and you're rather see a uniqueness error than overwrite the existing document (as `save()` would do). Afterwards, you'll need to go back and remove the original document.

Since you can't do all of this in a single atomic transaction, I would suggest the following order of operations:

- `findOne()` existing document by its `_id`
- Modify the returned document's `_id` property
- `insert()` the modified document back into the collection
- If the `insert()` [succeeded](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/), `remove()` the old document by the original `_id`