# How to insert a group of documents with a unique group id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in which some documents are in a group.

For example 2 and 3 are in a group:

```
{_id: 1, subject: "one",   groudId:  null}
{_id: 2, subject: "two",   groudId: "1234"} 
{_id: 3, subject: "three", groudId: "1234"}
{_id: 4, subject: "four",  groudId:  null}
```

Currently the `groupId` gets created at the same time when the documents of the group are created.

The Problem I have is that the design of our project currently creates the `group_id` on the client side and the clients then send it to the MongoDB.

I think that this can lead to the problem, that two clients generate the same `groupId` for two different groups.
Especially since the `grouId` is at this moment a concatenation of the current time and the amount of time the client was running. (Don't ask me why, it wasn't my idea.)

So how can I create a unique id for the groups with MongoDB?

My first Idea was to just take the ``` _id`` of the first task and make that the ```groupId`.
For example:

```
{_id: 1, subject: "one",   groudId:  null}
{_id: 2, subject: "two",   groudId:    2 } 
{_id: 3, subject: "three", groudId:    2 }
{_id: 4, subject: "four",  groudId:  null}
```

But `_id` gets created on insert so I can't set `groudId` on insert and have to do a later update.

So is this possible in any way without multiple inserts and/or updates?
Or is there a scheme to create a unique group Id on the client?

Comment: Currently the Id is created by MongoDB and not by me. So as far as I know I can't know the id before inserting the document.
Maybe it is a bit misleading that I wrote  `_id: 2`. That was just so I didn't need to write `ObjectID("553..")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the way you generate the `groupId` fields, you can always use MongoDB's `ObjectId()` as an identifier. The possibility of generating duplicate `ObjectId` identifiers is extremely low, as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle). You could then have your code do something like the following (in `mongo` shell syntax).

```js
// First Group
> var groupId = ObjectId();
> db.collection.insert({ "subject": "two", "groupId": groupId });
> db.collection.insert({ "subject": "three", "groupId": groupId });

// Second Group
> var groupId = ObjectId();
> db.collection.insert({ "subject": "one", "groupId": groupId });
> db.collection.insert({ "subject": "four", "groupId": groupId });
```

If you want to reuse a `groupId` generated before, you can fetch it from the collection and then reuse it.

```js
// Reuse First Group's ID
> var groupId = db.collection.findOne({ "subject": "two" })["groupId"];
> db.collection.insert({ "subject": "five", "groupId": groupId });
```

As a side note, I would personally prefer to have a second collection `groups` where I would keep a document for each group and take the `_id` of that document as the identifier for the `groupId` field in your other collection. That way you can easily track the IDs for each group and any other information you want to store per group.