# Does mongoose guarantee unique objectId while creating model object? If yes, how?

Tags: mongoose

```
MyModel = mongoose.model('test', { name: { type: String, default: 'Val '} });
var m = new MyModel();
... 
//Other application/process might add document with same object id. 
m.save();
```

m has _id set. Does mongoose guarantee it's unique by querying mongo while creating model object?

Comment: It does. One part of id is a random hash and another is a unique counter common accross collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongodb docs specify how the ObjectId is generated (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification).

ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

The ObjectId is generated in the client side MongoDb Driver Code, running on the client machine.

-> For most real world cases this can be considered unique.

(if it is not unique enough for your application, you probably have a large enough staff on your team to have an expert on unique ids:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5694803/2766511)

MongoDb also automatically creates an index with property "unique: true" on each collection for this field, to ensure that no two documents have the same objectId. (http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/index-single/#index-type-id, http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Comment: Thanks for the details. We have to guarantee guarantee it's uniqueness. But I missed last part in documentation, that is, it adds "unique:true" property, which will trigger some error.

Comment: yes, the unique: true index guarantees it "in this one collection" - the algorithm "almost" guarantees it universally.