# Syncing multiple mongoDBs and avoid duplicate _ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

## problem

I have a main register and x sub-registers which stream data to the main register. I sync these registers during the night with the main register. So during the daytime there will be created data in `x1,x2,...xn` and at night all the data is sent to the main register.

It is not very probable but it could be that for example `x1` and `x2` generate the same `_id`. Now if I sync them the first register would create the document and the second register would upsert (and thus overwriting) my document.

## solutions

### current

To prevent that I currently save the original `_id` under a field `refId` this is very awful because I can't use all the references and most of the functions on my main register.

### option I - autoincrement

I planned to switch to autoincrement `_ids` but I read that this is something you shouldn't do if you plan to scale:

https://blog.serverdensity.com/switching-to-mongodb-and-auto-increment/
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

### option II - modifying the sub-register _id

I'm already saving from which subregister my document came from. Thus I could check if an `_id` exists but has another sub-register. If so I could generate a new `_id` for the new document and give back the new `_id` to my sub-register. This sounds easy at a first glance but I do have a lot of references in my documents.

## Question)

What is a good solution to handle this issue with possible duplicate ids? is there an easier but effective way to solve this? E.g. prefixing the 24 digits ObjectId automatically.

Comment: Have you observed any duplicate ObjectIds. According to the answer on this post it is going to be highly unlikely this will be the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As it is unlikely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle) (although not impossible) that two identical ObjectIds are generated in the different sub registers, you could handle duplicate ObjectIds in your error handler. You can generate a new ObjectId if there is a unique key violation and there is a discrepancy in source register. As the error handler will not be called frequently, you can add more complex logic without affecting the overall performance.

You could, for example, generate a new ObjectId by cloning the source record and delete the original, or, alternatively you can create your own ObjectId and replace the machineId with  a registerId.

Comment: Ok cool that would be option II. In case of identical objects I do change the original _id? Or easier send back some error msg instead of saving and implement the logic then. I didn't know that the Id is generated that smart.

Comment: Yes, the simplest way to resolve the conflict, is to clone the source record and delete the original (you can't update the ObjectId).

Comment: If I have this two `_id`s: `555d8f f842 e7470b 447d8028` &
`555d8f f842 e7470b 447d8029` I can say that `447d8029` is the timestamp, `e7470b` is the machine, `f842` is the process and `555d8f` is the counter. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification, when exactly is the counter modified? It seems equal on both entries.

Comment: Is there a way to go through all collections at once and update every reference to that _id ? Or will I have to search through each collection and modify it with e.g. `findAndUpdate`. Because I got 6 collections which all have references to each other. So I would have to do it for every reference in every collection.

Comment: You will to search through each collection and update the id. It is slow, but it should not be called very often.

Comment: Just to ask if I have full control over all instances of my application, I probably could modify the processId and give each sub-register a defined processId than I would avoid collusions for sure. Is there a method (because I didn't find one) to set up a process id/machine id? Otherise I may could do this:
`var user = new UserModel();
var id = user._id;
user._id = id.slice(0,6) + "<my4digitsdHexId>" + id.slice(10,24);` I could define the `<my4digitsdHexId>` as `process.env.INSTANCEID` And write the method into `schema.pre('save', function(next) {`

Comment: Creating a custom ObjectId would work. I don't think you can set a defined processId.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is creating a custom mongoose ObjectId. As mentioned in this article https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification, the mongoose `_id` consists of several parts which make it very unlikely that two `_id`collide even if they are generated on different machines. To have more control over this process I take control over the processId section in the `_id`. Each subregister gets its own processID.

To achieve that I generated two functions:

1) Check if an override value for the `_id` is available, valid and if the register is a local one (no modifications required on the main register). Entries are only generated on my local register.

2) Modify the `_id`

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')
ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
registerType = require('./register-config.js').getType()#function gives back local/national

exports.useProcessId = ()->
  return process.env.REGISTER_PROCESS_ID? && process.env.REGISTER_PROCESS_ID.length == 4 && registerType == 'local'

exports.changeMongooseId = (data, next) ->
  id = data._id.toString()
  data._id = new ObjectId(id.slice(0,6) + process.env.REGISTER_PROCESS_ID + id.slice(10,24))
  return next()
```

This functions are called before I save a new document to the collection:

```
instituteSchema.pre('save', (next) ->
  data = @
  async.parallel
    eprd: (next)->
      validateEPRD(data, next)
    changeMongooseId: (next)->
      if useProcessId then processIdConfig.changeMongooseId(data, next) else return next()
    (err)->
      return next new Error(err) if err?
      return next()
)
```

I don't need to call the function on updates etc. because at this time it already has the unique `_id`.