# MongoDB (Possible amount of _id)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

There is a model - `Post` (using mongoose
`var Post = new Schema({...});`).
And every time new instance of `Post` model is created (`var post = new Post({...}); post.save(function (error) {...});`), the instance is given with an item, called: `_id` (`ObjectId("...")`).
I know it might be a stupid question, but: as much as database gets larger and larger, is there a limited amount `_id` or is it infinite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possibility of duplicate Mongo ObjectId's being generated in two different collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "limit" because the value is comprised partially of "a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch"

See this link: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/