# Referencing in mongodb with single or mutlple condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm not sure whether the auto generated id (object_id) of mongodb is unique across all the document or not. I've a dilemma about referencing.

Says I have a system which multiple users can create their own products and categories. So I will have product collection and category collection.

To get a category of a product, should I get the category by using user id and product id or product id alone is enough? since I will first get the product id using user id before I can find the category of that particular product.

Comment: have a check at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle

Comment: @LouisF. so I'm over worried? I don't have to put user_id in every collection to do double query am I right?

Comment: May I invite you to read this comprehensive documentation about how to model datas in MongoDB ? Depending on the nature of the relationship between product and categories, you will end up with different models. The link : ttps://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/