# MongoDB/Mongoose search and create of specific sub documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a REST API in nodejs/express/mongodb/mongoose. I've started using MongoDB/Mongoose recently and I still have some doubts.

What I'm trying to achieve is to access a specific user bag (a user can have multiple bags) and also I want to be able to add to that bags participants/payers. (a user bag can have multiple participants/payers)

My mongoose user modal contains the rest of the schemas. I created a schema for each one because I believe it would be easier to find a given bag or participant directly because of the ObjectId (not sure if this is correct).

Mongoose Modal/Schemas:

```
const PayerSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number
  }
});

const BagSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  type: {
    type: String
  },
  payers: [PayerSchema]
});

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'User name field is required']
  },
  bags: [BagSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I was able to create the CRUD controller methods for a new user, but I still not sure on:

1. Creating a new bag for a specific user (I was able to do this but not sure if it's the right way)
2. Creating a new participant in a specific bag for a specific user. (addPayer method is wrong need help here)

Check out my controller user/bags/participants methods:

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');

getAllUserBags: (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById({ _id: req.params.id }).then((user) => {
      res.send(user.bags);
    })
    .catch(next);
  },
  getOneUserBag: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.params.bagid);
    User.find({ 'bags._id': req.params.bagid}, {"bags.$" : 1}).then((obj) => {
      res.send(obj);
    })
    .catch(next);
  },
  createBag: (req, res, next) => {
    let bag = req.body.bag;
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.body.id},
      {$push: {bags: bag}
    }).then(() => {
      //Unnecessary - just to return update user with new bag.
      User.findOne({_id: req.body.id}).then((user) => {
        res.send(user);
      })
    }).catch(next);
  },
  addPayer: (req, res, next) => {
    let payer = req.body.payer;
    User.find(
      {'bags._id': req.params.bagid},
      {"bags.$" : 1},
      {$push: {payers: payer}
    }).then((obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
      //Unnecessary - just to return update user with new bag.
      // User.findOne({_id: req.body.id}).then((user) => {
      //   res.send(user);
      // })
    }).catch(next);
  }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Will there be a large amount of bags per user or large amount of payers per bag?

Comment: @willie17 - yes there could be a large amount in some small cases.

Comment: Do you need to query for something like "get all the bag" or "get all the payer"?

Comment: I just need all the bags for a user and I need to know all the payers for a user bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what we discuss, your `User` schema is good enough for your requirements, as long as making sure that one `User` document does not exceed the 16MB limit of MongoDB document.

---

> Creating a new bag for a specific user (I was able to do this but not sure if it's the right way)

Yours is fine. However, there are some improvements:

```
createBag: (req, res, next) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
      $push: { bags: req.body.bag }
    }, {
      new: true // this will make the query getting the updated document
    })
    .then(user => {
      res.json(user);
    })
    .catch(next);
})
```

---

> Creating a new participant in a specific bag for a specific user. (addPayer method is wrong need help here)

Since you decided to nest the 'bags', the `bag.id` might be duplicated among `User` documents. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle) to understand the possibility. Thus, I recommend using an `userId` along with `bagId`:

```
getOneUserBag: (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({
      _id: req.params.userId,
      bags._id: req.params.bagId
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) res.status(404).end();

      let bag = user.bags.id(req.params.bagId);

      res.json(bag);
    })
    .catch(next);
}

addPayer: (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate({
      _id: req.params.userId,
      bags: $elemMatch: {
        _id: req.params.bagId
      }
    }, {
      $push: { 'bags.$.payers': req.body.payer } // Use 'positional $' operator along with $elemMatch in the query to update only the matched bag
    }, {
      new: true // Do not forget the 'new' options to get the updated document
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) res.status(404).end();

      res.json(user);
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

and in the router

```
router.get('/users/:userId/bags/:bagId', getOneUserBag);
router.post('/users/:userId/bags/:bagId/payers', addPayer);
```

---

In the `getAllUserBags()`, you use the wrong syntax for `User.findById()`:

```
getAllUserBags: (req, res, next) => {
  User.findById(req.params.id) // Not { _id: req.params.id }
    .then((user) => {
      res.json(user.bags);
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips and explanations, It's working perfectly now. I still need to fully understand why I could have duplicate IDs. I feel like you are not sure if I should go for a nested approach.  A reference approach is the right way just in case sub documents get too big?

Comment: You must use reference approach when you meet any of these requirements: 1. A large amount of item will be stored in an nested array; 2. You need to query for somethings like "get all the bags", "get bag by bagId",... That's why I asked you 2 questions above. But since you are not sure whether your `User` will have a lots of bags so that it will exceed the 16MB limit or not, I am not sure whether you should use the nested approach or reference approach neither.