# Can the _id of an old deleted MongoDB document reappear/regenerate for a future document in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Can the _id of an old deleted MongoDB document reappear/regenerate for a future document in the same collection as the old _id is not in the picture because the associated document was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Please find this answer:
[Possibility of duplicate Mongo ObjectId's being generated in two different collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677237/possibility-of-duplicate-mongo-objectids-being-generated-in-two-different-colle)

As it states the BSON Object ID is partially based on "seconds since epoch" so it seems it should not be regenerated at different time.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like they are highly unlikely to be same for different collections so it should be good for the same collection, not able to figure out a case where it might regenerate again within the same collection considering it is not present anymore.